# finding how many times a graph crosses its horizontal asymptote

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a graph with the equation: $f(x)=\frac{1000(x+2016)(x-1001)(x-2019)}{(x+500)(x-500)(x-1000)}$

and it looks like this:

[image]

I want to know a way of determining how many times (if at all) this graph crosses its horizontal asymptote. I found a video where someone said to set the equation equal to its horizontal asymptote and solve. So

$\frac{1000(x+2016)(x-1001)(x-2019)}{(x+500)(x-500)(x-1000)}=1000$

Dividing by 1000 and cross multiplying, I get:

$(x+2016)(x-1001)(x-2019)=(x+500)(x-500)(x-1000)$

Without expanding all this out, how can I see how many times the graph crosses its horizontal asymptote.

I know it looks like it does on the right but I want to know how many times it crosses and where.

Comment: It's a quadratic equation, so there are at most two solutions.

Comment: And the picture is definitely not one of the given function; $f$ has poles for $x\in\{\pm500, 1000\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$
(x+2016)(x-1001)(x-2019) = (x+500)(x-500)(x-1000) \Leftrightarrow \\
(x+2016)(x-1001)(x-2019) - (x+500)(x-500)(x-1000)=0
$$
It shouldn't be too hard to see that the $x^3$ term cancels. 
The contributiors to the $x^2$ terms are
$$
- 2019 \\
+2016 \\
- 1001 \\
+ 1000 \\
+ 500 \\
- 500
$$
Which adds up to $-4$ $\Rightarrow $ you will get a second degree polynomial.

A second degree polynomial has two roots. They can either be real or complex. So you either has $2$ times of crossing, or $0$ times. Which of them is it?

Set $f(x) = 1000 \frac{(x+2016)(x-1001)(x-2019)}{ (x+500)(x-500)(x-1000)}$ then $f(1000,05) > 1000$ and $f(3000) < 1000$. Since $f$ is continuous between $x_1 = 1000,05$ and $x_2 = 3000$, by the intermediate value theorem $f$ must cross $1000$. Using the fact that it can only cross two timers och never. There has to be two crossings.

Comment: thank you! can you just explain what the last sentenec means? why are you doing f(2) and f(3000) and why does them being > or < 1000 affect the roots?

Comment: did you just pick two values to show that if they cross 1000, it had to go through 1000? there is no real significance of 2 and 30 right? thye are just arbirtrary numbers?

Comment: We came to the conclusion that the function either crosses 1000 two times or never. Since we found $x_1$ where $f > 1000$ and $x_2$ where $f<1000$ and using the fact that the function is continuous BETWEEN $x_1, x_2$. Then by the Intermediate value theorem $f$ must have crossed $1000$. Now since we found one crossing. And there can only be two crossing or none. There has be to two! @user130306